# Extract content of html with beautifulsoup while keeping some tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the content(text) of a html document. Howerver, I want to keep 'div' tag names.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is a text in div</div>
This is a text outside a div
<span>
    This is a text in span
</span>
<div>
    <div>
        This is a text in two divs
    </div>
    <span>
        This is a text in div > span
    </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<div>This is a text in div</div>
This is a text outside a div
<div>This is a text in two divs</div>
This is a text in div > span
```

How can I do it with beautifulsoup and python?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is...are you trying to extract the content of a div with div element itself also to be extracted?

Comment: I want to extract all the text from the html. But I want to keep <div> and </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup, NavigableString as ns
s = soup(your_html, 'html.parser')
def get_text(d, div = False):
   r_string = None
   for i in filter(lambda x:x != '\n', d.contents):
      if isinstance(i, ns):
         r_string = ('' if r_string is None else r_string+'\n') + re.sub('^[\n\s]+|[\n\s]+$', '', str(i))
      else:
         if r_string is not None:
             yield r_string if not div else f'<div>{r_string}</div>'
             r_string = None
         yield from get_text(i, i.name == 'div')
   if r_string is not None:
      yield r_string if not div else f'<div>{r_string}</div>'

print('\n'.join(get_text(s.body)))
```

Output:

```
<div>This is a text in div</div>
This is a text outside a div
This is a text in span
<div>This is a text in two divs</div>
This is a text in div > span
```

Comment: Thanks! This works pretty well! However, sometimes it may throw 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment'. How can I fix it?

Comment: @IvanEFan Hmm, did you change the code from my answer at all, or integrate it with other code? If not, can you post the HTML that, when running this function on it, the error was produced?